# ¿configurar hora servidor mysql xampp y consultas?

Tags: mysql

**hola chicos**

mi consulta es acerca de la zona horia en msqyl como configurar correctamente repecto a la semana es decir:

cuando hago la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT WEEK(NOW())
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

```
WEEK(NOW())
      51
```

y en realidad estamos en la semana 52.

mysql tiene la configuracion horaria del sistema.
hora colombia/bogota

```
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.time_zone | @@SESSION.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

tengo entendido que `la norma iso 8601` me da el formato de hora y fecha que necesito, habra alguna forma de configurar ese formato en mysql, ya que como menciono anteriormente en Colombia estamos en la semana 52 del año, y con la consulta me ajora 51.

usando la siguientes consultas me da el numero de semana:

```
SELECT WEEK(NOW(),1);
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

ambas dan el resultado esperado que es `52`

pero quisiera saber como seria con cualquier otra fecha.
ejemplo:

```
SELECT WEEK('2018-02-14',1);

SELECT WEEKOFYEAR('2018-02-14');
```

con ambos el resultado es 7 y quiero es el numero de semana (seria 52) sin importar la fecha.

Comment: Hola te dejo un enlace de un video para que pruebes con eso. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8GibZ1mS4Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**la ayuda me la dio un nuevo usuario.**

con la siguiente consulta tenemos el numero de la semana donde 1 indica el numero de dia que inica la semana:

```
SELECT WEEK(NOW(),1);
```

esta consulta tambien nos aroja el numero de la semana actual.

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

obtendriamos 52, numero de semana actual, colombia.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la misma consulta que usaste para verificar la zona horaria en el modo consola:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

Y después cambiar la zona horaria con la siguiente consulta:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = "Europe/Helsinki";
```

Para consultar en algún caso especificando el día de la semana, se utiliza un segundo argumento:

```
mysql> SELECT WEEK(NOW(), 1);
```

Donde el valor **1** indica que la semana inicia en lunes.

Aquí te dejo algunos enlaces de referencia:

[MySQL - Soporte de Zona Horaria](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.0/es/time-zone-support.html)

[MySQL - Funcion WEEK()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php)

Comment: me aroja este error la consola cuanto hago la consulta.                                                          mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = "America/Bogota";
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = "America/Bogota"' at line 1

Comment: Intenta con comillas simples por favor: - mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/Bogota'; - Tambien puedes intentar poner 'SYSTEM' y así consumirá la hora del servidor.

Comment: sigue arrojando el mismo error, ya tiene la hora del sistema pero debe estar mal con la norma, así como dije antes la semana no la calcula correctamente conforme a la norma iso 8601, debido a que estamos en la semana 52, y la consulta me arroja 51.

Comment: Al parece es un error de interpretación, según la revisión se debe especificar el día de inicio de conteo, es decir, en que día inicia la semana. Para nuestro caso debes ingresar: mysql> SELECT WEEK(NOW(), 1); - Donde "1" indica que la semana empieza en lunes. Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: jhonn Brxndon, gracias funciono con esa consulta, tambien funciona con esta SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());.